# Angular and Spring Boot over HTTPS in Apache2 Server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ssl, https, apache2

I'm hosting a web application in a virtual machine, using Apache2 as the server host. The backend part of the application is written in Spring Boot 2.0.6, and the frontend in Angular 5. My goal is just to be able to fully access to the application through HTTPS from an external source. This means access the client application, and for this one to be able to access the backend services, everything over HTTPS.

So far I have managed to configure the Apache server and the Spring Boot application to receive HTTPS requests. I can tell because I can get to the login page of the Angular application with HTTPS, but then, when it tries to make a request to the authentication services it hangs forever. I have generate auto-generated ssl ceritificates for both  the Apache server and Spring Boot application.

What configuration would be needed from any of the parts involved for the whole application (both client and server) to work over HTTPS? Is there any required configuration (library, setting, etc) for the Angular application in order to establish this communication with the HTTPS backend services?

Notes:

- The URLs of the services consumed by the Angular application are pointed as `https://` as well.
- There are no Inverse-Proxy configurations on the Apache server.
- The Angular application is deployed as a *dist* compiled, hosted by the Apache server.

Here is the Spring Boot config:

```
# The format used for the keystore. It could be set to JKS in case it is a JKS file
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/somekey.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=somepassword
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=somealias
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

Here are the configured Apache server files:

application-vhost.conf

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off

<VirtualHost *:80>
    #-BASIC-CONFIGURATION
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
    DocumentRoot "/angular_app_directory"

    Header set X-Frame-Options deny
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    
    #-DIRECTORY-CONFIGURATION
    <Directory "/angular_app_directory">
      #-SERVER-CONFIGURATION
      RewriteEngine on

      # Don't rewrite files or directories
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
      RewriteRule ^ - [L]

      # Rewrite everything else to index.html
      # to allow html5 state links
      RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

      #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@admin
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /angular_app_directory
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache-certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache.key
    <Directory /opt/sigap_pcc/web/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2.conf

```
...
<Directory /angular_app_directory>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

I'm aware that you can configure an Angular application to run over HTTPS locally, but (I'm begging you to correct me if I'm wrong) as far as I know, once the application is compiled and hosted on the Apache server, there would be no need to configure the Angular application, but the Apache server it self, which would be the one managing the requests.

I have read about redirecting HTTP request to HTTPS, but I'm not sure that's what I need, since redirecting should be a different process. I just want the HTTPS ones to work properly. Every configuration I have saw online shows how to configure Angular to run over HTTPS *locally*, but I have not found a solution in this.

Comment: Your Spring app is also configured to take HTTPS requests ? You will have to configure Tomcat with SSL. Most production configurations I have seen use reverse-proxy configuration. Any particular reason not to go ahead with that ?

Comment: Isn't the configuration shown above enough for ssl? Right now I don't have a say on configuring a reverse proxy, unfortunately I would have to find a solution without it. Unless there's any configuration relaying on it that helps to solve the problem.

Comment: You can’t have two apps listening to same ports. You have configured Apache for 80 and 443. How spring gets to react for https calls ?

Comment: Port 80 would receive HTTP connection while port 443 would receive HTTPS ones. As far as I know it works that way. In fact I'm able to at least connect through both HTTP and HTTPS because of enable those to ports. Am I wrong?

Comment: Which port spring boot is listening to ?

Comment: There are 3 services listening to 5200, 5201 and 5202 ports. Angular app is listening to 4201 port.